# How to lock the laptop keyboard in Debian?

Tags: linux, laptop, keyboard, debian

I have connected an external USB keyboard, and I would like to lock the laptop keyboard so I can put a book on top of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On modern systems, you enable and disable devices via the XInput2 system. The quickest way to access that is via the `xinput` command.

If it's not already installed on Debian (Gentoo needs `emerge x11-apps/xinput`), do so. Then use it like this:

```
$ xinput list
[list which reveals my main keyboard to have id=10]
$ xinput set-prop 10 "Device Enabled" 0
```

You may want to do your initial testing using a command like this though, just to make sure that any problems are guaranteed to undo themselves after 5 seconds.

```
$ xinput set-prop 10 "Device Enabled" 0; sleep 5; xinput set-prop 10 "Device Enabled" 1
```

Comment: Cool! Now I can plug the thin keyboard data cable back inside the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Covering the keyboard of a working laptop is not a good idea because some of the air flows through the keyboard. I managed to broke a HP laptop years ago when I left it for a long compilation with laptop lid closed.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, though.  It's also not a good idea to leave the keyboard open, because some small insects such as tiny ants and acarids will accidenty move inside.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure how to lock one keyboard and leave the other, but the hack'ish way is to run `xev`, it will steal all the keyboard's input until you specifically close it or move the input to another window.

Comment: No, this don't work because I do use an external USB keyboard at the same time. If run `xev`, it will eat all key strokes.